# Boot Loader failing to load windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Okay heres the problem.

On my desktop, I had windows 10.  I put another SSD in there and installed Ubuntu on that.  And when I booted the machine, Ubuntu loaded the boot loader and I could select the operating system I wanted to use, great.

Then I reinstalled Ubuntu because I got in a mess with my SQL server.  But ever since then, the boot loader looks different.  I lists Ubuntu at the top, and at the bottom instead of `Windows Boot Manager` (or something to that effect) it says `Windows 7`.  When I select the `Windows 7` I get a windows error message which basically says that it cannot load (I cannot remember the details of the error message, but it was large grey text on a DOS like screen).

So now I dont have the option to boot to windows, I have to do it manually from my BIOS which is a huge pain.  How can I get this functionality back? I tried mounting the Windows Disk (by clicking on it and viewing the files) in Ubuntu and running os-probe, but that didnt seem to sort anything.  The OS is there, so why can't I boot to it from the GRUB boot loader?

Answer (score 0):

Normally a simple `update-grub` should be sufficient for detect windows loader and be able to dual boot systems.

Comment: yeah, i've tried `os-prober`, `update-grub` but it doesnt ever find the Win10 boot.  It identifies a Win7 drive in `/dev/sdd1` but as far as I know that doesnt exist.

Comment: It detects the windows 7 loader because use the same as windows 10, the called windows 7 loader should be the windows 10 entry. 

Just for info, have you update to grub2?

If you have grub 2 try `update-grub2` or `grub2-mkconfig > /dev/null `

Comment: @WillWonka I seem to have update-grub2 but not grub2-mkconfig.  As I mentioned, when I run the Windows 7 loader from the boot menu i get a windows error.  When I run from the Boot menu in the Bios on the correct hard drive I get windows running fine.

Comment: @Chud37 can you check if the 'secure boot option' on BIOS is active? If it's the case, desable it and try again.